# Find Difference in Files but only show lines that dont exist in the other

Tags: string-comparison

I have 2 files that I need to compare, but each file has many of the same entries on different lines. How can I compare 2 LARGE files (many gb's) and only see the lines that dont show up in the other?

Example:

File1:
Line 1: Hello
Line 2: Goodbye
Line 3: Cake

File2:
Line 1: Cake
Line 2: Hello
Line 3: Test
Line 4: Goodbye

and only Line3 would be displayed because it is different, and everything else wont.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a particular coding language you are using?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I have a ton of strings from a process that I got using process hacker and have a modified version with different strings, mostly the same. I am using the strings to detect a cheat and need to find differences. I have tried EmEditor and n++ to compare but it does not seem to have what I need. Added an example to the post if you did not see it already.

Comment: For Windows there is a commandline tool called "Findstr" for small files, for large files "WinDiff" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/159214/how-to-use-the-windiff-exe-utility

Google for Linux or Mac.